# Making a:hover with padding. It moves, how can I prevent it?

Tags: html, css

My link: `<a href="#">Home page</a>`

Css:

```
a:hover
{
    padding: 5px;
    background: black;
}
```

When I hover over home page link, it moves, because I use padding. How can I avoid it? I want that black background would appear where the link is without moving its link and other links. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it by default:

```
a { padding: 5px; }
```

Or you can use margins:

```
a { margin: 5px; }
a:hover { margin: 0px; padding: 5px; }
```

This should work:

```
a {
    padding: 5px;
}
a:hover {
    background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the same padding to the base class (`a` with no hover).

Answer (score 1):

remove the padding on hover, if you want padding use which will be there all the times.

```
a{
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Did I answer your question?